# copying keypair from pem file to clipboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

Following these instructions and i;m using an ubuntu instance (in my local terminal): https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/
I have gotten to the step of running the command ssh-keygen -y -p (i'm using mac). It requests the address: Enter file in which the key is (/Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_rsa):
here I enter the full directory: /Users/me/.ssh/keypair.pem.
I do not enter any answers and then I get a response saying'Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase'. Am I supposed to see a key here to copy? because I don't. From here, I'm supposed to go back to my instance terminal and command: cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys, but I believe there should be a key to paste after the command. Anytime I paste here, it just grabs what the last thing I copied. please help!

Comment: If I do `ssh-keygen -y` or `ssh-keygen -y -f /Users/me/.ssh/keypair.pem` it works in my mac, no need to use -p in mac

Answer (score 0):

This is password less ssh 101. You'll find more than plenty resources on the web.

[Follow this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id) if you don't care to understand.

[This one](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication) has a little more details.

Couple of things I'll add here though:

- `ssh-keygen` will generate a pair, public and private. It might be in the same file. Or it might be just the private key, depending on options you provide. But you can always convert one format to another, or extract public key from private key using things like `openssl` or `ssh-keygen`. E.g. BSD  `ssh-keygen`'s -y option:

> -y This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print an OpenSSH public key to stdout

- your public key can be copied to remote host using `ssh-copy-id`, but it's just as good as opening `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on remote host and pasting your public key in it.
- when you ssh you can pass `-vvv` option and it'll probably detailed info on what it's doing.